# Create dynamic layout

Tags: android, textview

I am Android beginner, I am developing an app for college in which I need to schedule the class timing for the teacher, data come from a server but I don't know, how many subject allocated for a teacher, therefore I need to create this layout dynamically like this...
[image: layout]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about that textview with green background.
For that you need to first create drawable folder in your project's res folder
then craete one xml file in that folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/ur_color"/>

    <corners android:topLeftRadius="180dp"
        android:topRightRadius="180dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="180dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="180dp"/>

</shape>
```

then set this drawable as a background of that textview
lets say this file name is bg_txt.xml then u have to write in the property of textview

`android:background="@drawable/bg_txt">`

Answer (score 0):

try this create your layout like this

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Android"
            android:textColor="#000" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9:30 AM - 10:30 Am"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

       <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

create `custom_button` like this in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: basically, I am developing an app for college in which I need to schedule the class timing for the teacher, data come from a server but I don't know, how many subject allocated for a teacher, therefore I need to create this layout dynamically.

Comment: than whats the preoblem

Comment: the last item shows only, data retrieve by ArrayList